# Optimization SQL, not in/not exists?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a request, please tell me how you can optimize it?

```
    select distinct
    trunc(dw.mdf_date) as mdf_date
    ,dw.dss_id
    ,dw.raid
    ,dw.host_type
    ,dw.volume_name
    ,dw.volume_size
    ,dw.prv
    ,listagg(dw.hba_wwn,',' on overflow truncate '...' without count) within group (order by dw.hba_wwn) as wwn
  from
    dss_wwn dw
  where
    dw.volume_name not in ('ADMIN')
    and dw.volume_name not like '.%'
    and dw.hba_wwn is not null
    and not exists (select 1 from wwn shw where shw.wwn = dw.hba_wwn and shw.dic_type_eqp_id = 4 and rownum = 1)
    and not exists (select 1 from dss_vmhdd shw where shw.wwid = dw.disk_wwn and rownum = 1)
  group by
    trunc(dw.mdf_date)
    ,dw.dss_id
    ,dw.raid
    ,dw.host_type
    ,dw.volume_name
    ,dw.volume_size
    ,dw.prv
```

This request works for 23 seconds. 
And if you comment out this line, That works fast 0.2 seconds

```
and not exists (select 1 from wwn shw where shw.wwn = dw.hba_wwn and shw.dic_type_eqp_id = 4 and rownum = 1)

select count(*) from DSS_WWN --100000
select count(*) from WWN t --13000
```

UPD @Gro Thanks for your answer, really after I removed rownum=1 request fulfilled in 0.4 seconds

Comment: I tried to replace with "not in", But the result was negative

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231

Comment: BTW, no need to do SELECT DISTINCT, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Create an index on wwn, dic_type_eqp_id columns of  wwn table and try. 

By the way any specific reason why you have put rownum = 1 in both the not exists predicates. It may not help at all. DB engines bail out as soon as they find even one record from their 'exists' part of the query.

Comment: @Gro Thanks for your answer, really after I removed rownum=1 request fulfilled in 0.4 seconds